# How to inform view about error from controller

Tags: angularjs

In my view I have a login form. Upon submit I call a login method on my scope that is defined in the controller. From this method I call a service to do the actual login process. The service method returns a promise.

```
angular.module('auth').service('authService', ['$q', function($q) {
    this.login = function(credentials) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        // Do stuff and resolve or reject promise

        return deferred.promise;
    };
}]);

angular.module('auth').controller('authCtrl'), ['authService', function(authService) {
    $scope.login = function() {
        authService.login(credentials).then(
            function(res) {
                // Successfully logged in
            },
            function(res) {
                // Report error to view
            });
    };
}]);
```

How would I pass my error (returned by the promise rejection) to my view? Specifically to the ngModelController of specific (or all) input fields of my form.

Answer (score 0):

Add the error message to the scope, and bind to that in the view.

```
angular.module('auth').controller('authCtrl'), ['authService', function(authService) {
        $scope.errorMessage;
        $scope.login = function() {
        authService.login(credentials).then(
            function(res) {
            // Successfully logged in
            },
            function(res) {
               $scope.errorMessage = res;
            });
};
}]);
```

and in the view something like:

```
<p>{{errorMessage}}</p>
```

Of course you could make this more sophisticated, but this gives an idea of a general approach.

Comment: Like I said in my question, I'd really like to leverage the actual AngularJS validation system and assign my error to the ngModelController. With your approach I could not add validation error to single input fields and I also duplicate existing functions (error reporting).

Comment: Generally validation happens before you submit/post a form. The idea is that if the form isn't valid yon can avoid the request/response. It seems to me that you're not trying to validate, but rather display an error if something goes wrong server side. If you really want to use the validator, take a look at using controller.$setValidity.

Comment: You can't validate everything before submitting a form - some validation HAS to be server side. And when the request is a failure, it would be good to set an error state to the input fields that are actually wrong. The method you describe here may work for a general error message, but not if it's about a specific input. Also the visual error indication (like bootstrap 'has-error' class) would not be attached to the input. How could I use $setValidity, if I can't access the ngModelController within my controllre?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a specific answer in the form of code, but I would think you can access the form that is being submitted in your controller, parse out your error, and apply it to the appropriate field.

You can call $setValidity(reason,flag) on an item in your form programmatically, and I think that's what you are after.  The [angular docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/#!/api/ng.directive%3angModel.NgModelController#!) show the methods available.

So you'd do something like

```
// on error
function(res) {
  if (res.error === 'User exists') {
     $scope.loginForm.user.$setValidity('User is taken',false);
  }
}
```

This, of course, requires that you can determine in the UI which field is the problem based on the server response - if you want to display a message appropriate to the field.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you want to validate on the server as well, that goes without saying. However, ideally you'll perform your form validation independent of posting the form - this will provide a better UX. In this particular scenario, I'm failing to see what type of validation HAS to happen server side. You are authenticating a user. Presumably, their credentials are required. Possibly, you may want a format validator to make sure they're using an email address or something. Aside from that, it is useful to display errors, like a 401... you know, if the user enters bad credentials. Keep in mind, invalid credentials are not the same as an invalid form. Nonetheless, one way you *could* perform your necessary server side validations is to use a custom validator:

```
app.directive('myCustomValidator', ['$http', function($http) {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, el, attrs, ctrl) {
      $http({
          method: 'POST',
          url: '/api/validateSomething/',
          data: {'value': el.val()}
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, cfg) {
          ctrl.$setValidity('myValidationKey', data.isValid);
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, cfg) {
          ctrl.$setValidity('myValidationKey', false);
      });
    }
  }
}]);
```

This code isn't all-inclusive, and I did not test it, but hopefully it gives you an idea of one approach.